# Closing a Bootstrap modal hangs in Firefox when .form-control inside modal has focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am inspecting a curious case. I have a bootstrap modal containing some input fields in the modal-body.

Whereas on other pages it is no problem when a form field inside the modal has the focus and I close that modal, on this particular page something strange happens: The modal begins to fade out, until its opacity is 0. Than the whole fading process seems to stop:

- The `.modal-backdrop` is still there and visible.
- The `.modal` itself with `opacity: 0;` in the css still has inline style `display: block;`. It is lying over/covering the backdrop which thus is not clickable.
- The body has already lost class `modal-open`. There fore its scrollbar is visible again.

It doesn't matter whether the modal is closed because of a button with `data-dismiss="modal"` or with javascript. What matters is

1. A `.form-control` inside the modal has the focus. If I remove the class `form-control` from the inputs, the modal closes as expected, even if the input has focus. If I manually click somewhere else before closing the modal in order to remove the focus from the `.form-control`, the modal closes as expected. If I try to `blur()` or `unfocus()` all inputs in the modal, the problem still occurs.
2. Firefox browser, it doesn't happen with Chrome or IE

Interestingly, if I fiddle with Firebug when the modal "hangs", select the `.modal`, look at the css and change the opacity of class `.fade` (which is zero) to e.g. `0.1`, some process that seems to have waited continues, the modal is set to `display: none;` and the backdrop disappears.

Will have to dive further into this, as it only occurs in this page.

But maybe anybody has experienced something similar.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could make a fiddle.

Comment: I'm experiencing just the same issue: 2-3 seconds of hang between the button click and the "hidden.bs.modal" event. Same with or without fade effect. I was debugging a bit but haven't gone as far as you, and don't have more time now. I hope you (or Mozilla) will find the cause and the fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was an interference with jasny bootstrap. There is an issue regarding that problem on Github (and a quick solution):
https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues/293

Answer (score 0):

Set .form-control's transition property to none. This worked for me.

```
.form-control {
    transition: none !important;
}
```